# Deploying Java war and Rails app to Apache in Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jakarta-ee, deployment

is it possible to deploy java app and rails app to same EC2 sever. I have a rails app that communicates a java app via AJAX so I need to deploy both to same server. Is there any way to do that or any resource to see how to?

I guess it is possible by using apache2 with tomcat and passenger. Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

You can install two servers in diferent ports i.e. Apache HTTP on 80 and Apache Tomcat (or other) on 8080. Also you can use mod_jk if you want attend all your clients through Apache HTTP. MOD_JK enables to you to integrate Apache Tomcat and Apache HTTP.

Comment: is there any tomcat module to be in apache2 server. I guess Tomcat is standalone server. Is it right?

Comment: Tomcat is a standalone server